# Show a progress spinner Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to show a progress spinner when my doInBackground is processing.

From what I've been reading, here is what I am doing :

```
public class SearchMoviesAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    String URL = "http://localhost:3000/movies/search";


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd=ProgressDialog.show(SearchActivity.this,"","Please Wait",false);
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... args) {
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            Log.d("IDFB", args[0]);
            Log.d("Search", args[1]);
            params.put("idfb", args[0]);
            params.put("search", args[1]);

            Log.d("request", "starting");

            JSONArray json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest2(
                    URL, "POST", params);

            if (json != null) {
                return json;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray json) {
        pd.dismiss();
    }

}
```

This code is inside my `SearchActivity`.

The http request takes around 10 seconds to proceed and I want to add this spinner to avoid "MyApplication is taking too long to respond..."

Right now the spinner doesn't show up. If I delete `pd.dismiss();` in `onPostExecute`, it will be displayed after my request respond and never gets off.

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you executing the `AsyncTask`?

Comment: SearchMoviesAsync search = new SearchMoviesAsync();
            search.execute(UserId, query);
            try {
                JSONArray response = search.get();
                setMoviesList(response);
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

Comment: Yeah, it's the `get()` call that's doing that. It's basically turning your `AsyncTask` synchronous. Instead of using `get()`, initiate whatever code needs that `JSONArray` from `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Hum ok, but how can I wait that it's done before to use the `JSONArray`

Comment: nevermind, working well, thanks!